# All the folders under CUDA folder are Empty. (After installed the CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, gpu, cuda

I met strange a problem after I installed the CUDA 10.1 on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. I found all the files under the CUDA folder are Empty! Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance for your time.

Here are some details of my questions.

Firstly, I followed the steps below to uninstall the existing CUDA, and installed the latest version:

**Uninstall**

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*
```

**Install**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt updat
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

**Everything looks good at this moment, here are some install results:**

```
$ nvidia-smi

Mon May 25 02:32:42 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.82       Driver Version: 440.82       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K600         Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 31%   62C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    422MiB /   974MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   40C    P8     4W / 120W |     15MiB /  6078MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1432      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            31MiB |
|    0      1500      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          51MiB |
|    0      1681      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            95MiB |
|    0      1799      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          89MiB |
|    0      2687      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --shared-files   148MiB |
|    1      1432      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             5MiB |
|    1      1681      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             6MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
$ nvcc --version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

**Then the question came. Normally the CUDA should under /usr/local, but I cannot find it there. Hence I tried:** 
(The locate function has been updated with `sudo updatedb`)

```
locate cuda | grep /cuda$

/home/zihan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda
/home/zihan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/backends/cuda
/home/zihan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/cuda
/home/zihan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/include/c10/cuda
/home/zihan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/cuda
/home/zihan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda
/usr/include/thrust/system/cuda
/usr/lib/cuda
```

**Then I went to /usr/lib/cuda to check it. However, I found all folders inside CUDA are empty. I mean, everything disappears!**

```
/usr/lib/cuda$ ls
bin  include  lib64  nvvm  version.txt

# version.txt shows CUDA Version 9.1.85
```

```
/usr/lib/cuda/bin$ ls -l
total 0
# (questions are same in other folders, like lib64)

/usr/lib/cuda/lib64$ ls -l
total 0
```

**May I ask where these files go? Why this happens, and how can I fix that? Thank you a lot for your help in advance.**